# Cambio de Color de un Botón en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en WPF, tengo el xaml con unos botones, cuando doy clic en alguno de ellos cambian de color pero no se queda fijo, si no que el es intermitente, me pueden ayudar a resolver esto?

Se los agradezco.

Anexo el código del botón:

```
    private void btn_test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn_test.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0));  
    }
```

Comment: Explica a que te refieres con intermitente

Comment: Creo que es por el efecto del focus que se produce cuando das click al botón queda activo esperando.. como cuando una ventana se activa en segundo plano y queda 'intermitente' en la barra de tareas.. los controles tienen un efecto parecido.. yo creo que es eso. 

Intenta, luego de aplicar el color, setear el focus en otra cosa.

Comment: @LeonardoLynx gracias, era el focus